# Adding class inside another class

Tags: c#, list, class, generics

I have a class like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class arrayData
{
    public List<arrayData2> Levels;
}
public List<arrayData> Zones;

[System.Serializable]
public class arrayData2 { }
```

And I should add an item to the `Levels` collection:

```
void Start()
{
    Zones.Add(new arrayData());
    Zones[0].Levels.Add(new arrayData2());
}
```

The method keeps giving this error at runtime:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

Does anybody know what am I missing?

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples, you are missing to initialize the `Zones` **and** `Levels` collections.

You can either do it on the class that contains them or on the `Start` method.

For example, on the `Start` method:

```
void Start()
{
    var Zones = new List<arrayData>();
    Zones.Levels = new List<arrayData2>();

    Zones.Add(new arrayData());
    Zones[0].Levels.Add(new arrayData2());
}
```

Or on the class containing them:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class arrayData
{
    public List<arrayData2> Levels = new List<arrayData2>();
}
public List<arrayData> Zones = new List<arrayData>();

[System.Serializable]
public class arrayData2 { }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this made me understand the structure

Comment: That's what we are here for :)
You can now follow the idea and implement it as you will (for example in the constructor of the class containing the list).

Answer (score 5):

In `arrayData` you need an actual instance of `Levels`, which you can create in the constructor:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class arrayData
{
    public List<arrayData2> Levels;

    public arrayData() 
    {
        Levels = new List<arrayData2>();
    }
}
```

And you must create a new instance of `Zones` prior to using it:

```
var Zones = new List<arrayData>();
Zones.Add(new arrayData());
Zones[0].Levels.Add(new arrayData2());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `Zones` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the Levels collection

```
public List<arrayData2> Levels;
```

You can do it in the ArrayData constructor or in Start() method